# The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Function". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "register"

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

So redux thunk is giving me this error (or maybe not redux-thunk but the extension)

```
The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Function".
Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "register"
```

**store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()
);

export default store;
```

**reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import register from './register';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    register
});

export default reducers;
```

**action**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function changeDOB(payload) {
    return dispatch => {
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I remove the `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()` the error disappears, I don't know why the extension is giving me that error, but it looked like I'm the only one who encountered it. I searched on google and can't find anything related to this error.

BTW, there is also one more error, so onload that error pops up and when I try to test the action, it produces the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

but when I remove this part `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()` I see a `test` on my console which means that the action was successful (because that's what it does for now). But I need that part for development purposes right, so how do I deal with this. I think I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your store enhancers are not set up properly. applyMiddleware is an example of a store enhancer. Store enhancers are higher order functions that add custom functionality to the store.

**Basically all your store enhancers are expected to be passed in via function composition through the same argument.**

Compose is used when you want to pass multiple store enhancers to the store. Store enhancers are higher order functions that add some extra functionality to the store.

To make things easier, there's an npm package to install:

```
npm install --save redux-devtools-extension
```

and to use like so:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

Here is an alternative set up from the redux docs which you can use if you don't want to use redux dev tools when your app is in production

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as reducers from '../reducers/index';

let reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
let middleware = [thunk];

let finalCreateStore;

// In production, we want to use just the middleware.
// In development, we want to use some store enhancers from redux-devtools.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore);
} else {
  finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    require('redux-devtools').devTools()
  )(createStore);
}

let store = finalCreateStore(reducer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I came up with the answer because of this, maybe the video that I watched and the blog post that I read were outdated and did not even mentioned anything about this. Thanks.

Comment: I do have a question though, what is the difference between using this `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()` and this `require('redux-devtools').devTools()`? I managed to make it work without using that `redux-devtools` package.